# ChangeServiceConfig2 windows function in 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-services, 64-bit

Is ChangeServiceConfig2 windows function in 64bit OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. (Is there a specific problem you're having?)

Comment: My code was was not working in 64 bit hence I got the above doubt,  the issue is fixed for now.